# sharethis plugin's facebook share count is not correct

Tags: facebook

[image]

I am using sharethis plugin. As per facebook documentation Like count is fine(shares+ likes+ comments) count.

But why fshare is  showing fshare count as 757? Also whenever I am sharing using this button the like buttons count increases and share button count is unchangeable.  Why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Your "share" button and your "like" button are not the same thing (confusing, I know).

Basically there are two different ways for Facebook users to interact with your site, and the two different counts reflect those two different ways.